# url and paths helpers on laravel when document root has changed

Tags: php, laravel, url, assets

I'm becoming to use laravel framework (v5.7). I recently changed my document root and virtual host as follows (the aim was just don't show "public" on the url's):

Document Root:

```
DocumentRoot "${INSTALL_DIR}/www/laravel/public"
<Directory "${INSTALL_DIR}/www/laravel/public/">
    Options +Indexes +FollowSymLinks +Multiviews
    AllowOverride all
    Require local
</Directory>
```

Virtual Host:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName localhost
  ServerAlias localhost
  DocumentRoot "${INSTALL_DIR}/www/laravel/public"
  <Directory "${INSTALL_DIR}/www/laravel/public/">
    Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Require local
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Once it was done, my css and js files didn't point to the right place (normal, I thought). I looked in the laravel documentation but I started to be confused about the right way of generate urls for css and js files in my project.

Laravel has different helpers to generate urls (such as url() and asset()) and other helpers to point to folders (base_path(), public_path(), resource_path()).

I also searched on Google about this and I began more confused because many people use the asset helper to generates url of files which are located on the public folder (not the resources folder).

My questions are the following:

1. If my css and js files are located in the public folder (public/js and public css), which is the correct way to generate those urls once the document root folder and virtual host has changed the folder to look in?
2. Should I use the asset helper or the url helper to generate them?
3. May I use a combination of helpers to do it?
   For example: url(public_path('css/style.css'))

PD: my "own helpers" for you:
In both cases, asset() and url() prints the same:

- asset('') and url('') --> "http://localhost/"
- asset(public_path('')) and url(public_path('')) --> "http://localhost/C:\wamp64\www\laravel\public"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like

```
asset('css/style.css')
```

is the right way to do it.